# How do I make a static Radio Group in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker, radio-group

This is turning out to be harder than I expected. If I want a radio group that just has static options (Yes, No), how do I set that up through the App Maker UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably this should work for you. In the options binding do the following:

```
['Yes','No']
```

Then also make sure that you deselect the 'Allow null' setting so that your only options are yes or no. Alternatively if your options widget is linked to a datasource field and you only want yes or no as options, then in your model field settings expand the 'advanced' option and find your possible values section and enter Yes and then No and then set the options binding to:

```
@models.YourModel.fields.YourField.PossibleValues
```